# Order queryset by field in intermediary table with recursive m2m relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have followers/followees system in my django app and I want to order by user's followers and followees by action time when appropriate action is happend.
My models:

```
class UserFollow(models.Model):
    followee = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_set') # The one who is followed
    follower = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followee_set') # The one who followed
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # Other fields which don't matter in this question
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='followees', symmetrical=False, through='UserFollow')
```

For example i have user and i can get all his followers in reverse order when they followed this user:

```
followers = user.followers.all()
# returns <QuerySet [<CustomUser: follower1>, <CustomUser: follower2>, ... , <CustomUser: follower{n}>]
```

The following qs of course doesn't work:

```
followers = user.followers.order_by('-userfollow__timestamp')
```

I can get followers pk in right order and then get followers objects:

```
followers_pk = user.follower_set.values_list('follower', flat=True).order_by('-timestamp')
# returns <QuerySet [n, ... , 3, 2, 1]>
followers = CustomUser.objects.filter(pk__in=followers_pk)
# returns <QuerySet [<CustomUser: follower1>, <CustomUser: follower2>, ... , <CustomUser: follower{n}>]> (user objects in reverse order)
```

Any suggestions or tips to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example:

```py
class Doctor(...):
    patients = models.ManyToMany('Patient', ..., related_name = 'doctors', through = 'Registration')

class Patient(...):
    doctors = models.ManyToMany('Doctor', ..., related_name = 'patients', through = 'Registration')

class Registration(...):
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', ..., related_name = 'registrations')
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', ..., related_name = 'registrations')
    timestamp = models.DateTime(...)
```

Then we can do:

```py
# get a specific doctor:
doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id='<doctor-id>')

# get and order all patients that registered with this doctor by the registration timestamp:
patients = Patient.objects.filter(doctors=doctor).order_by('registrations__timestamp')
```

In your example this would look like:

```py
# the user we want the followers of:
celebrity = CustomUser.objects.get(id='<celebrity-id>')

# their followers ordered by timestamp:
followers = CustomUser.objects.filter(followees=celebrity).order_by('follower_set__timestamp')
```

Comment: Ye, that works with small fix: order_by('-followee_set__timestamp'). Thank you.